# Variable latency in Windows networking

Tags: windows, networking, latency

I have a PLC that sends UDP packets every 24ms. "Simultaneously" (i.e. within a matter of what should be a few tens or at most hundreds of microseconds), the same PLC triggers a camera to snap an image. There is a Windows 8.1 system that receives both the images and the UDP packets, and an application running on it that should be able to match each image with the UDP packet from the PLC.

Most of the time, there is a reasonably fixed latency between the two events as far as the Windows application is concerned - 20ms +/- 5ms. But sometimes the latency rises, and never really falls. Eventually it goes beyond the range of the matching buffer I have, and the two systems reset themselves, which always starts back off with "normal" levels of latency.

What puzzles me is the variability in this variable latency - that sometimes it will sit all day on 20ms +/- 5ms, but on other days it will regularly and rapidly increase, and our system resets itself disturbingly often.

What could be going on here? What can be done to fix it? Is Windows the likely source of the latency, or the PLC system?

I 99% suspect Windows, since the PLC is designed for real time response, and Windows isn't. Does this sound "normal" for Windows? If so, even if there are other processes contending for the network and/or other resources, why doesn't Windows ever seem to catch up - to rise in latency when contention occurs, but return to normal latency levels after the contention stops?

FYI: the Windows application calls `SetPriorityClass( GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS )` and each critical thread is started with `AfxBeginThread( SomeThread, pSomeParam, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL )`. There is as little as possible else running on the system, and the application only uses about 5% of the available Quad-core processor (with hyperthreading, so 8 effective processors). There is no use of `SetThreadAffinityMask()` although I am considering it.

Comment: You are running on a non real-time multi-tasking operating system.  Lots of crapola is taking advantage of the multi-tasking, you are not generally interested in, say, Windows Update installing an update while you are monitoring the PLC.  Only really good way to get soft real-time behavior is to start from Windows Embedded and use the system builder.  Ensures that nothing is turned on at all and still gives the option to turn only the hoopla  you actually need..

Comment: "real-time" is always a concept relative to the application. Windows manages to play audio tracks without noticeable pops and clicks (mostly), or handle video streams at 50+ frames per second, and that is good enough "real-time" response for most people. So I'm not trying to do anything Windows hasn't shown itself to be capable of - I'm interested in (a) understanding precisely what is going on and (b) programming my application to achieve comparable performance.

Comment: Between what two events? Receiving an UDP packet, and receiving an image via TCP? If yes, that's likely TCP window adjustments. If you're minimizing latency, better use UDP for both, or at least research how to lower the TCP latency.

Comment: Sorry - the image comes via GigE Vision protocol, also UDP-based. And the image always arrives first - it is the UDP packet from the PLC that ends up being delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have two devices, PLC and camera, which send data to the same PC using UDP.

I 90% suspect networking.

Either just buffering / shaping mechanism in your switch/router (by the way, I hope your setup is isolated, i.e. you have not just plugged your hardware into a busy corporate network), or network stack in either of devices, or maybe some custom retransmission mechanism in the PLC. Both IP and Ethernet protocols were never meant to guarantee low latencies.

To verify, use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to view the network traffic.

For best experiment, you can use another PC with three network cards.

Plug your three devices (windows client, PLC, camera) into that PC, and configure [network bridge between the 3 cards](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10). This way that second PC will act as an Ethernet switch, and you’ll be able to use Wireshark to capture all network traffic that goes through that.

Comment: Also, your router might classify the camera's traffic as realtime CCTV data, and act appropriately. As a first step, ensure your router has QoS disabled.

Comment: Also, ensure you don’t have anything wireless anywhere between your devices, only copper.

Comment: Excellent suggestion on Wireshark - still new to it, and had not appreciated one can capture from two NICs at once (both the camera and PLC send to the PC on networks isolated from all other traffic). This will at least tell me if the latencies are "real" or being generated by the Windows protocol stack.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be a complex interaction between multiple factors, most of which don't convey any information useful to others... except as examples of "just because it seems to have been running fine for 12 months doesn't give you licence to assume everything was actually OK."

Critical to the issue was that the PLC was a device from [Beckhoff](http://www.beckhoff.com) to which several I/O modules were attached. It turns out that the more of these modules are attached, the less ability the PLC has to transmit UDP packets, despite having plenty of processor time and network bandwidth available. It looks like a resource contention issue of some kind which we have not resolved - we have simply chosen to upgrade to a more powerful PLC device. That device is still subject to the same issue, but the issue occurs if you try to transmit at roughly every 10ms, not 24ms.

The issue arose because our PLC application was operating right on the threshold of its UDP transmit capabilities. The PLC has to step its way through states in a state machine to do the transmit. With a PLC cycle of 2ms, the fastest it could ever go through the states in the state machine with the I/O modules we had attached turned out to be every 22ms.

Finally, what was assumed at first to be an insignificant and unrelated change on PLC startup tipped it over the edge and left it occasionally unable to keep up with the normal 24ms transmit cycle. So it would fall progressively further behind, giving the appearance of an increasingly latency.

I'm accepting @Soonts answer because careful analysis of some Wireshark captures was the the key to unlocking what was going on.